# Create functions in llvm pass with arguments and return type of type uint32_t and long double

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-gcc

Is there any way to create a function with return type and arguments as uint32_t and long double?
For example, we can create argument of type int as follows:

```
 std::vector<Type*>FuncTy_args;
 FuncTy_args.push_back(IntegerType::get(M.getContext(), 32));
```

In the llvm link, 
http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Type.html. I can see only

`static PointerType *   getInt32PtrTy (LLVMContext &C, unsigned AS=0)`

```
static PointerType *    getDoublePtrTy (LLVMContext &C, unsigned AS=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LLVM IR, all types are represented in terms of type and number of bits. Once they are compiled, they lose the information of signed and unsigned. So once a C code is compiled to LLVM IR, types like uint32_t would become `i32` and `long double` would become `x86_fp80` since it's 80 bit floating format. Here is some information about [types](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#integer-type). I think you can use this [function](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Type.html#ace5611e40c0a2dbdc2c6cbc93bea180c) for `long double`. As for `uint32_t`, you can use [this](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Type.html#aad6d60332fc8355f254131d715eb9b06) function.

Comment: The link to `this` function no longer points to a specific function. Can you give the name of the function, please?